# iptables on centos

Tags: linux, centos, iptables

I would like to disable my machine to reach a remote access and to block incoming traffic from the same network. so actually I need to block output traffic to network "X" and input traffic from network "x" but I want all other traffic to be open input and ouput

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming you want to start with no other rules

`iptables -F`

`iptables -X`

`iptables INPUT -p ACCEPT`

`iptables FORWARD -p ACCEPT`

`iptables OUTPUT -p ACCEPT`

the rules you want:

`iptables -I INPUT -s <ip> -j DROP`

`iptables -I OUTPUT -d <ip> -j DROP`

then run

`service iptables save`